# Generic Array Without Reflection

Tags: java, java-8

I already read some of the answers following which I know 1 of the technique of creating a generic array is using reflection but what of I write the below generic method for creating an array? Is this potentially dangerous in any way?

```
public <E> E[] getArray(int size, Class<E> e) { 

          E[] arr = (E[])new Object[size];    
          return arr;    

}
```

Comment: Looks wrong to me as you've actually created an array of `Object` not an array of `E`. Have a look at [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java).

Comment: Yeah! I agree! But I want to know can it cause a runtime exception in any way?

Comment: what's the type input `Class<E> e` you're planning to use for ?

Comment: @AnkitSingodia Try it and see. I think if you actually try and assign an object of type `E` into an element of the array, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @nullpointer: I used that to have a compile time check. Because of Class<E> param, the below statement gets an error at compile time:

Integer[] strArr = myStack.getArray(10, String.class);

And so the client is bound to retrieve the array in the appropriate data type i.e String in above case.

Comment: *below statement gets an error at compile time*... which IMHO, is a better way in which compiler can help you with to prevent trying something like `Integer[] strArr = myStack.getArray(10, String.class);`, those types are not compatible to be casted.

Comment: By the way, the `Class<E> e` is unused in your current code. If you remove it, your method invocation would look like : `Integer[] strArr = myStack.getArray(10)`.. What's still an unsolved piece of this puzzle is what is `myStack` an instance of, does it imply any type bound to it?

Comment: If you have a `Class` object representing the element type, why not use `Array.newInstance(e, size)` instead of `new Object[size]`?

Answer (score 3):

It simply doesn't work.

The compiler will allow you to write:

```
String[] sarr = new YourClass().getArray(10,String.class);
```

but in runtime you'll get an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: Nope. I tested it for the case you mentioned. It runs just fine.

Comment: @AnkitSingodia that's very strange, since I also tested it. Which Java version are you using? (not that I think it should make a different, though) Can you post the exact code you tried?

Comment: My bad. That indeed produces a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and generics are concepts from two different eras of Java, which are not designed for being mixed. If you want typesafe genericity, why not use `ArrayList` instead of the array?

Comment: Yeah! Arraylist indeed does go well with generics, but just to get some concepts clear in my head - I was trying this :)